# ffmpeg filter_complex multiple overlays - why are they not syncing properly

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm setting up live streaming using three overlaid inputs in ffmpeg. O:v is a webcam directly connected to the streaming box (a headless linux box) while 2:v and 3:v are ultra-low latency UDP streams from two remote R-Pis.

The filter_complex argument I'm using (that works, with all three video inputs perfectly in sync) is [0:v] fifo [v1];[2:v] fifo [v2]; [3:v] fifo [v3];[v1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[sync1];[v2]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[sync2]; **[v3] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+5/TB [sync3]** ;[sync1][sync2] overlay=x=W-w:y=H-h [out1];[out1][sync3] overlay=x=0:y=H-h [vfinal]

What I don't understand is why I am having to add +5/TB to [sync3] via setpts (in bold above)? If I omit that, [3:v] is synced in to the stream noticeably ahead of the other two inputs. My best guess is that this may be to compensate for the processing time of the first overlay [sync1][sync2] which is introducing extra latency into that part of the stream.

Importantly - the value of the extra pts compensation has to be dialed in by hand and will be specific to the underlying hardware used. So the question is, is there a way of getting ffmpeg to calculate this automatically so I don't have to worry about keeping it dialed in, in production?

Thanks for reading! I'm at the limit of the ffmpeg docs here...